Delete file using AppleScript as root with administrator privileges does not work if file was created/downloaded by user, not root
I need to solve the following problem on macOS: I must work with some files using a combination of AppleScript and Shell.
For example, I have a file in the file system in folder /Users/username/Documents/Test/test.zip which has 777 permissions.

I can delete the file from the terminal as current user by rm /Users/username/Documents/Test/test.zip

I can delete the file from the terminal as sudo by sudo rm /Users/username/Documents/Test/test.zip

but if I do this from within an AppleScript with administrator privileges, it is not possible; I get a permission error.


=> It strongly depends on who downloaded the file to the hard drive!
The Applescript script is like this:
-- Define the path to the file you want to delete 
set filePath to (path to documents folder as text) & "/Users/username/Documents/Documents/Test/test.zip" 

-- Use `do shell script` with `rm` command with admin privileges to delete the file
do shell script "rm " & quoted form of POSIX path of filePath with administrator privileges

This is an example. My goal is to call my app to manipulate some files in the system. I can create files in the system directories from within this script, but I can never delete (or overwrite) them if somebody other than me (root in this case) created them. If I created them, then I can delete them freely.
If I download the file from within the AppleScript as root, I can then delete it using either method a) b) or c). Method c) is most important to me. The problem is, if I want to download a file that already exists in that location but someone else created it, then I am not able to update it.
I tried to set permission to target files (chmod) 0777 (and similarly to its folders), change the owner to the root (chown), remove xattributes but nothing helped. I also tried removing non-mutable attributes. It is irrelevant in this case what is removed from the file. It looks like it only depends on who created it.
I tried to execute the rm from within the AppleScript script via a separate Shell script or osascript but still see the same issue. Simply put, macOS SIP is blocking it. No matter which file, this happens on all three of my Macs (Ventura, Sonoma) so it is consistent; the file system is not damaged. My file system is OK … I've run disk check. This also happens to any file I try on the other Macs. If I disable SIP, it works, but this is of course not the solution.
Script Editor and my app, which I call from within the AppleScript, has full disc access and my app binary is in 0777 mode.
Method c) must work, as I am actually calling my app from within the AppleScript, but it does not even work from the AppleScript script itself, so the problem is there, not my app. There must be some settings or workaround for this.
The reason I am using AppleScript is I need to copy some files to the system folders and this I can do as root, not as user and of course I can  call my app with sudo from terminal, but this is not a good solution, therefore I thought AppleScript would be the right approach.
UPDATE:
If I try this script
-- Define the path to the file you want to delete
set filePath to "/Users/martin/Documents/Test/test.zip"
-- Convert file path to POSIX path
set posixFilePath to POSIX path of filePath
-- Create the shell command to delete the file
set shellCommand to "sudo rm " & quoted form of posixFilePath
-- Run the shell command with administrator privileges
try
do shell script shellCommand with administrator privileges
display dialog "File deleted successfully."
on error errMsg number errNum
display dialog "Failed to delete file: " & errMsg
end try
Then I get fail with error message:
Failed to delete file: rm: /Users/martin/Documents/Test/test.zip: Operation not permitted
If I download the file as root and then try to delete it, then it works, so the path is OK. The issue is macOS from some reason (maybe simple, but to me not logical )does not allow to delete files downloaded by other users than root.

Your applescript set filePath… will not work. It will produce a path that looks like this: "MacHD:Users:username:Documents:/Users/username/Documents/Documents/Test/test.zip". Instead try something like this: set filePath to (POSIX path of (path to documents folder as text)) & "Test/test.zip", which should produce something like this: "/Users/username/Documents/Test/test.zip". Then give it a try.

Hello yes, thank you for correction. You are right. But I have tried and the permission issue persists. The issue is not the path to the file, but macOS permission from within the apple script. I have edited the question with more information
